# Getting error in date format in sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a entry in table named to_log where date in end_tmp ='12-SEP-20'. I have a requirement that data should be selected for end_tmp < (sysdate-30). When I am checking (select sysdate-30 from dual) I am getting '12-SEP-20'. So for this date my query should not return any data as it should be less than sysdate-30 but in my case

```
 (SELECT log_idr,trunc(end_tmp)
  FROM to_log 
  WHERE end_tmp < (SYSDATE-30);
```

Is actually return data. What can I do?

Comment: 12-SEP-20, is that year 2012?

Comment: No it is today's date year 2020

Comment: end_tmp has dates in string format or is the column of type  DATE ?

Comment: Your question title says you're getting an error, the body says you're getting data returned - so which is it?

Answer (score 0):

From what you posted, could be

```
where to_date(end_tmp, 'dd-mon-yy', 'nls_date_language = english') < sysdate - 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding trunc worked. I added trunc(end_tmp)<trunc(sysdate-30) and it worked now